# Proper use of sub sub fragments with (Child)FragmentManager

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

How do I properly use Fragments in Fragments?

My (simplified) use case is following, I have an activity with a layout fragment and this fragment theirself contains a sub fragment... all fragments are added manually to their parents...

```
----------------------------------------------------------
- Activity                                               -
-                                                        -
-                                                        -
-     ---------------------------------------            -
-     - Fragment                            -            -
-     -                                     -            -
-     -    -----------------                -            -
-     -    - SubFragment   -                -            -
-     -    -               -                -            -
-     -    -               -                -            -
-     -    -----------------                -            -
-     ---------------------------------------            -
-                                                        -
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now in my activity's `onCreate` I do following:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
{
    // I create the fragment
    mMainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_main, mMainFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
else
{
    // I retrieve the fragment
    mMainFragment = (BaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main);
}
```

And in my fragments `onCreate` I get/create my SubFragment:

```
mSubFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SubFragment.class.getName());
if (mSubFragment == null)
{
    mSubFragment = new SubFragment();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_sub, mSubFragment, SubFragment.class.getName()).commit();
}
```

**Problem**

After screen rotation, my SubFragment is added twice... If I use the activity's `FragmentManager` then it works... But why does it not work with the `ChildFragmentManager`? Of course, the Fragment is a new fragment, but the activity is a new one as well, so why does it work with the activity's `FragmentManager` but not with the parent fragment's one?

In a fragment, I should use the fragments `ChildFragmentManager`, shouldn't I?

Comment: Not the same question, but for others who come here, see the related [Communication between nested fragments in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491655/communication-between-nested-fragments-in-android/39563977#39563977).

Answer (score 12):

You should add `SubFragment` to `Fragment` the same way like you add `Fragment` to `Activity`. I mean adding `Fragment` to `Activity` should look like:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ....
   if (savedInstanceState == null){
      //add fragment
      mMainFragment = new MainFragment();
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_main, mMainFragment);
      transaction.commit();
   }
 }
```

Adding `SubFragment` to `MainFragment` should look like:

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater i, ViewGroup c, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
           mSubFragment = new SubFragment();

           //add child fragment
           getChildFragmentManager()
                   .beginTransaction()
                   .add(R.id.fragment_sub, mSubFragment, "tag")
                   .commit();
        }
      }
    }
```

or you can add child fragment to `Fragment` in `onCreate` method

Comment: i think this is what the OP posted in question.

Comment: @lionelmessi no, he uses onCreateVIEW vs onCreate. I think this is the correct answer

Comment: If fragment A holds B, B holds C then should fragment C also be added using child fragment manager?