# How to use SupportFragmentManager on a Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to use support fragment manager in a fragment but it says SupportFragmentManager doesn't exist in the current context.

Here's my code

```
        private void Adapter_RateItemClick(object sender, DriversAdapterClickEventArgs e)
        {
                RatingFragment editAluminiFragment = new RatingFragment();
                var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                editAluminiFragment.Show(trans, "Rate");
        }
```

I used

> using FragmentManager = Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager; 
>   ?
>   what should I do next

Comment: Most likely you will want to call into the activity and do the fragment transaction there.  If you really want to do something inside the fragment, you should use the child fragment manager, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676690/proper-use-of-sub-sub-fragments-with-childfragmentmanager

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531643/how-to-get-access-to-getsupportfragmentmanager-or-supportfragmentmanager-in-frag) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [there is](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment) documentation AndroidX Fragment class (it is similar for support v4, but you definitely should switch to AndroidX if you can). And as you can see there, there are two methods for working with fragments: [getChildFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getChildFragmentManager()) and [getParentFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getParentFragmentManager()). I suppose you want to use child fragment manager to show some dialog, so in your case it will be

```
private void Adapter_RateItemClick(Object sender, DriversAdapterClickEventArgs e)
    {
            RatingFragment editAluminiFragment = new RatingFragment();
            editAluminiFragment.Show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Rate");
    }
```

Comment: @GioGarcia wait, I didn't see it is xamarin :)

Comment: aw :< is there another way aroud sir?

Comment: @GioGarcia did you try to use [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.fragment.childfragmentmanager?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9](child fragment manager)? Where is your Adapter_RateItemClick method located?